# You need vim compiled with Python 2.6, 2.7 or 3.2 and later support for Powerline to work

Tags: python, vim

При запуске vim вылетает сообщение You need vim compiled with Python 2.6, 2.7 or 3.2 and later support for Powerline to work. Vim version 8.0.707. Debian. 
vim --version показывает

```
-python       
-python3
```

Подскажите, где активировать нужную версию python!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Поставить `vim-nox` или `vim-gtk` (если нужен `gvim`).

По умолчанию в debian стоит минимальный `vim-tiny`.

Comment: Слава Одину, то, что надо!

Answer (score 2):

Нельзя "активировать" - нужно скомпилировать с поддержкой соответствующей версии `python` (о чем вам прямо и говорят). Для этого нужно соответственно сконфигурировать `vim`:

```
./configure --with-features=huge \
    --enable-multibyte \
    --enable-rubyinterp=yes \
    --enable-pythoninterp=yes \
    --enable-python3interp=yes \
    --with-python3-config-dir=/usr/lib/python(version)/config \
    --enable-perlinterp=yes \
    --enable-luainterp=yes \
    --enable-gui=gtk2 \
    --enable-cscope \
    --prefix=/usr/local
```